# Error when creating adwords campign using api

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm using google adwords api to create campaign directly from wordpress post or page by adding campaign name, keywords, budget etc.

```
$campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class);
        $campaignService->SetClientId( 'xxxxxxxxxx' );
        $operations = [];

        // Create a campaign with required and optional settings.
        $campaign = new Campaign();
        $campaign->setName('Interplanetary Cruise #' . uniqid());
        $campaign->setAdvertisingChannelType(AdvertisingChannelType::SEARCH);
```

But I'm having the next error:

> [OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ operations[0], OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ operations[1]]

It seems we need to set customer id for this so we are using `SetClientId()` but its giving another error of

> Function ("SetClientId") is not a valid method for this service

Comment: You should show some code

Comment: Sorry have updated code now

Comment: please show aswell the piece of code where you build the session with   `new AdWordsSessionBuilder()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change/set the `clientCustomerId` with php sdk you have to do so when creating Adwords Session:

```
$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
    ->withClientCustomerId(clientCustomerId)
    ->build();
```